# How to change the URI of an InternalEObject

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, emf

I would like to change the URI of InternalEObject.

I know I can get the URI by calling:

```
EcoreUtil.getURI(internalEObject);
```

What would be the correct procedure to change the URI for the internalEObject in question? Not just getting the string. Creating a new identical InternalEObject and give it a new URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

It is possible to use the utility functions present in EcoreUtil wich is a part of EMF.

The following snippet did the job:

```
for (InternalEObject def: defs) {
  URI uri = EcoreUtil.getURI(def);
  def.eSetProxyURI(URI.createURI(uri.toString().replaceAll(STRING_CONSTANT1, STRING_CONSTANT2)));
}
```